# Why does my definition in Python only work once and then returns empty lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I tried to make a definition in Python that allows me to retrieve the index of specific columns in a file. The function works when I call it the first time, but after that it returns empty lists.

This is the test data I used:

```
ChrPos,C1P1,C1P2,C1P3,C1P4,C2P1,C2P2,C2P3,C2P4,C3P1,C3P2,C3P3,C3P4
P1,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,CC,TT,TT,TT,TT,AA,GG
P2,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,GG,GG
P3,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,CT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT
P4,TT,TT,TT,TT,GG,GG,GG,GG,GG,GG,TT,TT
A1,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,AA,TT,AA,AA
A2,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,GG,GG
A3,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,AA,TT,TT
A4,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT
B1,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,CC,TT,TT,TT,TT
B2,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,GG,GG
B3,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,TT,CC,TT,TT,AA,AA
B4,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,AA,GG,GG
```

This is the code I used:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

InFileName = "~/scripts/test_devide.csv"

InFile = open(InFileName, 'r')


def get_columns(InFile, Chr_Number):
    line_count = 0
    for line in InFile:
        if line_count == 0:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            element_list = line.split(',')
            index_chr = [i for i, element in enumerate(element_list) if re.search('C%d.*' % (Chr_Number), element)]

        return index_chr

chr1_index = get_columns(InFile,1)
chr2_index = get_columns(InFile,2)
chr3_index = get_columns(InFile,3)

print(chr1_index,chr2_index,chr3_index)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [] []
```

My intent was to use the definiton to find the index of all column headers starting with "C1" (chromosome 1) and use this index to write these columns to a seperate file. And to do this for multiple chromosomes (C2, C3 and so on).

Comment: You have to explicitly reset the file pointer (`InFile.seek(0)`) before trying to read from it again.

Comment: Either that, or read the entire file into a list: `lines = InFile.readlines()`

Comment: better to read the file once as @Barmar suggested. file reads are slower.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however, the real data set I want to use it for contains 2 million columns and +500 rows... would it still be a good idea to read the entire file into a list?

Comment: Better would be to pass a *list* of column numbers, and populate a list of lists all in one pass though the file.

Comment: Although, wait: you aren't actually iterating over the file; you are just reading the first line and immediately returning. You really could just read the first line from the file `line = InFile.readline()`, then pass `line` to multiple calls of (a suitably modified) `get_columns`.

Comment: @chepner, thanks again, Im still very limited in my Python knowledge, your suggestions are much appreciated